# Scatter Bubble chart drill down issue

Tags: looker-studio

The drill down doesn't seem to be working properly in the scatter bubble chart, depending on what is selected as bubble color. In my original chart with the option Bubble color all dimensions would show values as I drill down but the chart would break after some drilling down or the next day.

In styles I cant select Bubble color as an option it sort of defaults to it at times but the only options are my drill down dimensions. My alternatives are to have color none where the drill down works but no dimensions values are showing or to select the color by the same dimension as the default drill down choice in that case only that dimension will show values regardless of what drill down choice is made.

Color options:

[image: color options]

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f767dd17-71e2-4d3f-abe5-15b41689c311)

[Data Set (Google Sheets)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LlgSRstL2epvEY2un-V6IWiOZ3Q9j6LMd-zSqSrl1_M/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been or still is related to this [bug report](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/11604525?hl=en). I've gotten it to work by choosing only url metric and selecting color by url then adding a drop down and adding other metrics below. The style option changes by itself to Bubble color which is what we want.